# Angular JS web application scrolling jams in iOS browsers

Tags: javascript, html, ios, angularjs, web-applications

I've built a web application that was operating fine until iOS 8 came out. A subset of pages began to jam and not scroll. I have been trying to find the pattern in the pages that scroll fine and ones that don't, but can't come up with any conclusions.

Sample pages that don't scroll

- http://emanuel.alenjohnglina.com/#/1-3_night
- http://emanuel.alenjohnglina.com/#/4-5_mass-readings?reset=true

Page that still scrolls - http://emanuel.alenjohnglina.com/#/1-1_ramsha

Any guesses to what could be causing the jam or where to debug next?

Comment: I found the culprit, but I don't know how to do without it. This snippet of CSS code allows momentum scrolling `.off-canvas-wrap {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:  touch;
 }`. This still doesn't explain why only a few pages are affected.

Comment: You should probably mark the question as resolved then.